# reading from a text file into a vector - newline described as an empty vector what gives?

Tags: c++

C++ primer has the following description and example (p. 110):

```
assume we have a vector<string> named text that holds the
data from a text file. Each element in the vector is either a sentence or an empty
string representing a paragraph break. If we want to print the contents of the first
paragraph from text, we’d write a loop that iterates through text until we
encounter an element that is empty:

for (auto it = text.cbegin(); it != text.cend() && !it->empty(); ++it)
        cout << *it << endl;
```

What I don't understand is how can a newline character `\n` be interpreted as an empty vector when reading from a text file or even user input?

I set up a loop to read input into a vector as follows, which is the method described in the book:

```
vector<string> text;
    string s;
    while (cin >> s)
        text.push_back(s);
```

Receiving inputs in this manner erases white space including newlines does it not? How would I interpret newlines and store them as empty vectors? Why does the book describe it in this manner?

The book describes input re-direction in the earlier pages by doing the following in CMD in Windows:

```
cd [PROJECT LOCATION]
PROJECT.EXE <input.txt>output.txt
```

The above is how I would read input from a file into my program.

Comment: Your loop doesn't honor the definition of what that loop expects. It expects either *sentences* and empty strings. Your loop builds a list of whitespace (including newlines) separated tokens. You *probably* want a `std::getline` loop, not a formatted string extraction loop.

Comment: Yes I understand that's what it expects, but how can I create a loop that reads data into a vector in the manner that it describes because the only input method that involves vectors is the one I wrote above. How can a newline be an empty vector when reading input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `getline()` if you want to keep the whitespace:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> text;
    std::string s;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, s))
    {        
        text.push_back(s);
    }

    // output first paragraph
    for (auto it = text.begin(); it != text.end() && !it->empty(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Input on Console:

```
Paragraph 1
does not stop yet
but stops now
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>, storing an empty line, which will later cause `!it->empty()` to fail and thus the output loop to stop.

```
Paragraph 2
will not be output
```

<kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, being the EOF (end of file) character followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the combination of both which will cause `getline()` to end.

Comment: So if `getline()` sees a line with just a new line character (`\n`) the loop terminates?

Comment: @Spellbinder2050: no, it terminates at Ctrl+Z, which is the EOF character for text

Comment: So that vector contains both paragraphs and a newline character in between for 3 elements total? Why isn't the 2nd paragraph displayed?

Comment: The vector contains 6 elements, line 1, 2 and 3, an empty line and line 1 and 2 of the second paragraph.

Comment: The second paragraph isn't displayed, because line 4 is an empty line and the output loop has `!it->empty()` as a condition